# How to get total of all items in recycler view

Tags: java, android

I have recycler view and spinner in activity depending on spinner value post request has been sent to server after which recycler view populated in which every row have some cost. I want to add this cost of every row.
Screenshot is given below:

[image]

In screenshot we can see No. of quantities are 2 which cost 40 like this other row also have some value.SO I want to add all these costs from each row and showing it in lower left area where `ToTAL` is written.

Here is my code:

**activity_select_pack.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SelectPack">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/marketCard"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/textMarket"
        android:text="Select Market Name"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textMarket"
        android:id="@+id/marketSpinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_back"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/products"
    android:layout_below="@+id/marketCard"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_above="@+id/totalLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/totalLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_back"
        android:text="Total:00.00"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_but"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Generate bill"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</RelativeLayout>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

**selectpack_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crown"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/marketName"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/marketName"
            android:background="#adadad"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product No."/>

         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="300"
             android:id="@+id/productNo"
             android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/productNo"
                android:background="#adadad"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Page"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="300"
                android:id="@+id/page"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/page"
                android:background="#adadad"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MRP"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="300"
                android:id="@+id/mrp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mrp"
                android:background="#adadad"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inner pack"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="300"
                android:id="@+id/innerPack"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/innerPack"
                android:background="#adadad"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Outer pack"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="300"
                android:id="@+id/outerPack"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/innerPack"
            android:background="#adadad"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/qtySpinner"
                android:background="@drawable/qty_spinner"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TOTAL"
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="ORDER"
                android:id="@+id/order"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:background="@drawable/login_but"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**SelectPack.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_pack);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    assert ab!= null;
    ab.setTitle("Select Pack");
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    marketSpinner = findViewById(R.id.marketSpinner);
    progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
    products = findViewById(R.id.products);

    products.setHasFixedSize(true);
    products.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Select market");
    categories.add("Crown");
    categories.add("Long Book A4");
    categories.add("Long Book");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    marketSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    marketSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            if(item.equals("Select market")){
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else{

                getData(item);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

private void getData(String item){

     progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     products.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

     productList.clear();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("name",item)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().post(formBody).url(URL).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                        if(jsonArray.length() > 0){

                           products.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }

                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String str1 = object.getString("market");
                            String str2 = object.getString("product_no");
                            String str3 = object.getString("page");
                            String str4 = object.getString("mrp");
                            String str5 = object.getString("inner_pack");
                            String str6 = object.getString("outer_pack");

                            Log.d("prod",str2);

                            ProductsModel model = new ProductsModel(str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6);

                            productList.add(model);
                        }

                        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),productList);
                        products.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final IOException e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    products.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    });

}
```

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<ProductsModel> productList;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<ProductsModel> productList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.selectpack_layout,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ProductsModel model = productList.get(position);

    holder.marketName.setText(model.getMarketName());
    holder.productNo.setText(model.getProductNo());
    holder.page.setText(model.getPage());
    holder.mrp.setText(model.getMrp());
    holder.innerPack.setText(model.getInnerPack());
    holder.outerPack.setText(model.getOuterPack());

    List<String> qty = new ArrayList<>();
    qty.add("Select qty");
    qty.add("1");
    qty.add("2");
    qty.add("3");
    qty.add("4");
    qty.add("5");
    qty.add("6");
    qty.add("7");
    qty.add("8");
    qty.add("9");
    qty.add("10");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, qty);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    holder.qtySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    holder.qtySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            if(!item.equals("Select qty")){

            int qty = Integer.parseInt(item);

            int cost = Integer.parseInt(model.getMrp());

            int val = cost * qty;

            holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(val));

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView  marketName,productNo,page,mrp,innerPack,outerPack,total;
    Spinner qtySpinner;
    Button order;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        order = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order);
        qtySpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qtySpinner);
        marketName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.marketName);
        productNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productNo);
        page = itemView.findViewById(R.id.page);
        mrp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mrp);
        innerPack = itemView.findViewById(R.id.innerPack);
        outerPack  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.outerPack);
        total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.total);
      }
   }
}
```

Someone please let me know how can I get and add total cost from each row and show it in lower left area. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

You can use array and append the value of each cell in it and never clear it, then create a function in your adapter that return with this array, here you cal add it's items.

Comment: How can I implement this into code please can you update your answer with code.